# Usar interpolacion en Jade dentro de un each

Tags: html, jade

Estoy tratando de iterar con un each en Jade, para generar un menu, pero dentro del a el href no me itera el array paginas usando la interpolacion #{pagina}. Sin embargo fuera de esa etiqueta si funciona.

```
  -var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]

 ul
   each pagina in paginas
     li: a(href="#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
```

Lo cual genera lo siguiente:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#{pagina}.html">inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#{pagina}.html">nosotros</a></li>
      <li><a href="#{pagina}.html">servicios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#{pagina}.html">clientes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#{pagina}.html">contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Dato adicional: Estoy utilizando prepros para compilar.

Comment: Si, pero finalmente tuve que colocar directamente la etiqueta <a href="#{pagina}.html">#{pagina}</a> dentro del .jade en vez de a(href="#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
Supongo que debe ser algo de prepros , saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: sorry no manejo mucho la pagina , pero creo que ahi lo hice

Answer (score 1):

tu array no esta siendo reconocido

si lo borras y trabajas asi?

```
ul
    each pagina in ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
        li: a(href="#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
```

lo cual genera lo siguiente:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="inicio.html">inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="nosotros.html">nosotros</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="servicios.html">servicios</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="clientes.html">clientes</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

mira lo probe en linea y funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, pero no me resutla. De hecho me itera el segundo   #{pagina}, pero el que está dentro del href no itera

Comment: @noobChileno puedes poner mas codigo?

Comment: arriba inclui el html que me compila

Comment: @noobChileno has probado con mi codigo?

Comment: asi es, incluso lo probe creando otros archivos independientes, y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: @noobChileno talves tu problema es en otro lado, actualice mi respuesta con screenshot demostrando que funciona bien.

Comment: @noobChileno que tal sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: No me resulta :/ , sera el compilador que uso?

Comment: estoy utilizando prepros

Comment: @noobChileno evidentemente el compilador es el problema

Comment: Y eso a que se debe?

Comment: @noobChileno no se a que se debera, espera a que alguien mas te ayude , modifica tu pregunta detallando ese aspecto

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esto me ha servido y no me ha dado ningun error, espero te ayude.

```
-var paginas = ["inicio", "nosotros", "servicios", "clientes", "contacto"]

ul
  each pagina, i in paginas
    li: a(href= paginas[i] + ".html") #{pagina}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice 3 pruebas distintas (no mucho) con el array que suministraste, use codepen.io para hacer las pruebas, y aunque una .pug algunas de estas formas puede servirte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código:

```
    -var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
    ul
        each pagina in paginas
            li: a(href="#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
    ul
        each uno, i in paginas
            li: a(href=uno[i] +".html") #{uno}
    ul
        each otro in paginas
            li: a(href=otro[$index] +".html")= otro
```